# WCF Streaming not working

Tags: wcf

I've just spend the afternoon reading almost every post on Stack Overflow about WCF and streaming. I am still getting an error which I cannot trace. Below is my client and server definitions and the error I'm getting. If anybody can either point me to a post that will solve my issue or provide me with an answer it would be greatly appreciated.  If I change to transferMode="Buffered" then everything works (if the files are small enough). This feels like something small I'm missing ...

Web.config

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>

  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the value below to false and remove the metadata endpoint above before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />

    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="Streamer"  maxReceivedMessageSize="67108864" transferMode="Streamed"/>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>

    <services>
      <service name="MyService">
        <endpoint address="/" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="Streamer" contract="IService1"   />
      </service>
    </services>

  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
  </system.webServer>

</configuration>
```

App.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <system.serviceModel>
        <bindings>
            <basicHttpBinding>
                <binding name="Streamer" maxReceivedMessageSize="67108864" transferMode="Streamed" />

            </basicHttpBinding>
        </bindings>
        <client>
            <endpoint address="http://localhost:52316/Service1.svc" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="Streamer"
                contract="Service1Reference.IService1" />

        </client>
    </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

Exception :

```
... System.ServiceModel.ProtocolException was unhandled   Message=The remote server returned an unexpected response: (400) Bad Request.   Source=mscorlib   StackTrace:
    Server stack trace: 
       at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelUtilities.ValidateRequestReplyResponse(HttpWebRequest request, HttpWebResponse response, HttpChannelFactory factory, WebException responseException, ChannelBinding channelBinding)
       at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelRequest.WaitForReply(TimeSpan timeout)
       at System.ServiceModel.Channels.RequestChannel.Request(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)
       at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.RequestChannelBinder.Request(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)
       at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)
       at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)
       at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage message)
    Exception rethrown at [0]: 
       at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
       at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)
       at MyClient.Service1Reference.IService1.UploadFile(UploadFileMessage request)
       at MyClient.Service1Reference.Service1Client.MyClient.Service1Reference.IService1.UploadFile(UploadFileMessage request) in c:\temp\WCFSTREAM\MyClient\Service References\Service1Reference\Reference.cs:line 87
       at MyClient.Service1Reference.Service1Client.UploadFile(String fileName, String key, Stream fileData) in c:\temp\WCFSTREAM\MyClient\Service References\Service1Reference\Reference.cs:line 95
       at MyClient.Program.Main(String[] args) in c:\temp\WCFSTREAM\MyClient\Program.cs:line 24
       at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
       at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
       at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean ignoreSyncCtx)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart() InnerException: System.Net.WebException
       Message=The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.
       Source=System
       StackTrace:
            at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
            at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelRequest.WaitForReply(TimeSpan timeout)
       InnerException:  ...
```

Comment: Have you tried adjusting the maxReceivedMessageSize config property?

Comment: Yep. Done that on both the client and the service.

Comment: Can you post more of the web.config? "Streamer" isn't defined anywhere in what you posted. Just post everything inside <system.servicemodel>

Comment: I've just noticed that my code fragments didn't come through so nicely. It is now updated and looks much better.